# Collect List of Installed Apps using App Widgets with Collections?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am completely new to the concept of app widgets with collections, let alone app widgets. I want to create an app widget that can collect a list of the users installed apps and put them in a list view in the app widget, that can be checked. The widget would update the list accordingly. 
I looked around to see if there was a way to go about doing this and I found that using app widgets with collections might be a possiblity.
Am I going about this the correct way? Any resources or tips to help me do this is apperciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are kind of asking everyone to write your app from you (this is far too generalized a question).  Perhaps you should split your questions into something more manageable, and do some initial research on your own to better define your problem.

You can put a listview in a widget (you can put pretty much any UI element in any control in Android - since everything is just a subclass of View).

To get the list of all apps a user has installed, use the PackageManager (the list of applications is captured in a List, which is a type of Collection):

```
        PackageManager packageManager = null;
        List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        try {
            packageManager = getPackageManager();
            if (packageManager != null) {
                appsList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
            }
        } catch (final Exception e1) {
            Log.v("PackageManager", "This is my error: ", e1);
        }
```

Comment: I agree, sorry about that. I've done some researching of my own and will post more specific questions from here on out. The main question I was trying to ask here you answered (how to get list of apps user installed) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Glad to help, and good on you for learning more so you can focus your questions.  Good luck with Android.

Answer (score 0):

This API will crash in some HTC devices etc. We do it the below way to find apps which have at least one Activity the below way.

```
        List<String> installedPackageNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for(ResolveInfo info : resolveInfoList){
            if(info.activityInfo != null && info.activityInfo.packageName != null){
                installedPackageNamesList.add(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            }
        }
```